# Motherboard for Intel HD 4000 graphics

Tags: intel-graphics

I am about to buy a new desktop, and I am concerned whether all motherboards that support 3rd Generation Intel processors, will support Intel HD 4000 graphics. I'm keen to know as I saw some motherboards stating "Enhanced support for Intel HD 4000/2500" while some stating "Enhanced support for Intel HD 2000/3000". Does this mean that not all motherboard supporting 3rd Generation Intel processors will support Intel HD 4000 graphics?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound , is it that Haswell denote 4th gen processor and IvyBridge denote 3rd gen?

Comment: Link to Intel HD 4000 graphics for Intel 3rd gen CPUs: http://ark.intel.com/products/family/65504/3rd-Generation-Intel-Core-i5-Processors/mobile

Comment: @radwajUrma I will be nice and simply provide http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture) to respond to that comment

Comment: @Ramhound, I see All 4th gen processor listed down. i also saw all 3rd gen CPU listed in the IvyBridge wiki link. So IvyBridge do have Intel HD 4000 capabilties. ex Intel core I3 3225 CPU

Comment: Looks like Intel does their GPU weird. Haswell's GPU is 4200-P4700 and 5000-5200 [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics) If the motherboard is an Ivybridge then any Ivybridge CPU will be supported. Haswell change the socket and the Ingel HD Graphic product line with its release. My previous statement was because the question was not clear. Ivybridge had HD Graphics, HD Graphics 2500, and HD Graphics 4000 GPUs